# How to make the background tilemap in Unity3D have a "far away fog effect" filter in a sidescroller game?

Tags: unity, tilemap, graphic-effects

I would like my background made of the same tiles as my foreground but with a filter which makes it appear further away from the camera.

Making the objects smaller is easy, I just have to decrease the scale of the tilemap.

But I also want it to have a "fog effect". So for example if the sky is blue then the tiles will be as blueish as far they are from the camera.

How could I implement this?

Example for fog effect:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about a 2D sidescroller just like in the image? Or a 3D one?

Comment: 2D, just like in the image.

Comment: What's wrong with making the background actually further away and applying a fog effect?

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in 2D fog, you can simply change the color of the background sprites so it looks like it is behind a fog. In Unity, you can simply change the color of the `Image` component, or the color of the material (depending how you are drawing them).

For example, try adding a dark grey color to it.

This has the disadvantage that you can't apply light-colors, as white means use the Texture's original color. Instead, you can make a trick shader-wise, if you feel comfortable with that, simply making pixels of an object whiter than they should, the further away they are from the camera.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution for dark colors. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Unity support other blend modes? Screen or multiply the background layer by a constant to get a good fog look.

Comment: @rebusB multiply is the default I think, that's why if you put all white, all colors will have the value `1f` so the texture keeps its original colors. I'm not sure if it's possible to do addition, which would support white as well, that's why I suggested a custom shader, so the user can have total control

Comment: Right! Blend modes are pretty core to shader code... Turns out the article I was reading on Unity Blend Modes was plugging a plug-in so crafting shaders would be the way to go.